# Newsletter queue limits to 40 rather than sending to all 70,000

Tags: cron, newsletter

My newsletters are not sent to all of my subscribers. I have 70,000 subscribers in my Magento database. After adding the template, then queuing the newsletter, schedule a date and time for it, it doesn't send out automatically at the scheduled date and time.

I have to login to admin and click "Send Newsletters", however when I do it only sends the newsletter to 40 each time. It's very long-winded to send to 70,000 subscribers like this!

I've looked at the settings and the Magento cron job is working fine, it just doesn't send to more than 40 subscribers.

Comment: Hi. Not shouting !!! Sorry typed with caps lock on! Sorry.

Comment: better now ... :)

Comment: @HassanHafez always a good idea to proof read things before saving :)

Comment: Hi Robbie. Thank you for proof read my questions. I think is much better and make more since! :)
I wonder if you could help with the solution too? @RobbieAverill

Comment: could you post your cron job code?

Comment: * * * * * ! test -e /var/www/vhosts/peppertreelondon.co.uk/httpdocs/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /var/www/vhosts/peppertreelondon.co.uk/httpdocs/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always

* * * * * ! test -e /var/www/vhosts/peppertreelondon.co.uk/httpdocs/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /var/www/vhosts/peppertreelondon.co.uk/httpdocs/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default

Comment: are you sure this is not a limitation at your SMTP gateway?

Comment: If you have that many subscribers, I would consider using a third-party service such as [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) or [Constant Contact](http://constantcontact.com).

Comment: @MagenX not sure if I have limitation on SMTP gateway. I just contacted my hosting provider to find out. Many thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Joseph Yes I most likely will use mailchimp soon! Thanks
Just want to find solution for the time being. Thanks

Comment: "I have to login to admin and click "Send Newsletters", however when I do it only sends the newsletter to 40 each time. It's very long-winded to send to 70,000 subscribers like this!" That sounds like a timeout. And of course it is not intended to send 70000 newsletters at once with a request from the admin panel. The cronjob does not send any newsletter emails?

Answer (score 0):

Check app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\Model\Observer.php, and see what's the value in your scheduledSend .  The default is send 20 per queue per scheduler running.  So you might want to override it properly in a custom module or app/local depending on the version you are using.